# Setting Shader in LineDataSet of MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart, linear-gradients

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Is there any way, I can apply `setShader` function to `LineDataSet` of `MPAndroidChart`. I have generated rainbow spectrum color and applied it to `LinearGradient` and now i want to set it to `LineDataSet` or I want to sent the lineargradient under the area of graph. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Drawable` (which can be a gradient / shader) and set it to be the fill-drawable of the `LineDataSet`:

`lineDataSet.setFillDrawable(...)`

Comment: Sorry for this but how can i make `Drawable` from `gradient/shader`?